# How to initialize and interate over a variable with JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, javabeans

It's the first time for me on JSP and Web Applications in general. I have a problem with this code I'm writing:

```
<%
            List<Location> result = new ArrayList<>();
            if (basicSearchBean.validate()) {
                 result = basicSearchBean.getResult();
            }
            pageContext.setAttribute("result", result);
        %>
    <div style="width: 800px; margin-left: 50px; margin-top: 30px;">
        <%
            if ( result.size() > 0 ) {
        %>
                 //VISUALIZATION PART
        <%
            }
        %>
    </div>
```

This code is part of a jps page where the user fill a form and then press a type submit button that redirect on the page itself. After the `validate()` (method of the javabean basicSearchBean) the private variable "result" of the basicSearchBean is set. The code always fails in `if ( result.size() > 0 )` with the error NullPointerException. Do I initialize the variable in the wrong way inside the jsp page?

Here is the code of the bean

```
public class SearchBean {

    //other attributes...

    private List<Location> result;


    public List<Location> getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(List<Location> result) {
        this.result = result;
    }



    public SearchBean() {
    }

   //Getters and setters.... 

    public boolean validate() {

        if(this.nation.equals("") || this.city.equals("") || this.checkin == null|| this.checkout == null) {
            return false;
        }
        try {
            this.result = FilteredSearch.getListOfStructures(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I found a guide on the Web where a method like `getListOfStructures()` return a variable initialized as `final`.

Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see any problems in the code you have shown here. Your variable is correctly initialised, the null value is coming from the bean. Presumably this is because FilteredSearch.getListOfStructures() is returning null, but this is something you would have to debug yourself.

However... writing chunks of Java inside your JSP page is extremely bad practice and you should avoid this as much as you possibly can. See [this page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/servlets-jsp-140445.html) for some good practice guidelines.

I think you will find this task much easier using [JSTL](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm) and [EL](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_expression_language.htm). They basically provide libraries of tags for common functions and mechanisms for accessing data from your beans, iterating over data, etc. It saves you writing a lot of boilerplate code and means you can in most cases avoid using Java in the page itself.

In addition, you can also create your own tags ([tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_custom_tags.htm)) which allows you to keep the Java logic separate from the layout of your page.

If you use these technologies well you should end up with a JSP page containing only JSP/HTML tags and all the logic will be separated out into your bean and any tag classes which is far easier to write, understand and maintain than having logic in your presentation layer.